# UISplitViewController: displayModeButtonItem is hidden when using DisplayMode.primaryOverlay

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am struggling with the UISplitViewController, trying to collapse the master with a button-press with `DisplayMode.primaryOverlay`

So, a little bit of background:

I have a `SplitViewController`, a `MasterView Controller` and a `DetailViewController`. I want to have a button in the navigation bar, that collapses the `MasterView`. There are plenty of posts that cover this functionality and it woks quite well:

SplitViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewController.DisplayMode.allVisible

    }
```

DetailsViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    configureView()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true

}
```

When run with this configuration, everything works fine: 
[Visible MasterView and visible button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2n44.png) 
[Collapsed MasterView and visible button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJMFR.png)

But when the DisplayMode in the SplitViewController is changed from `DisplayMode.allVisible` to `DisplayMode.primaryOverlay` the button in the navigation bar is not visible anymore. 
[Visible MasterView and hidden button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI5yc.png)

So my question is, if it is possible to have the collapse-Button visible when using `DisplayMode.primaryOverlay`?